# Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:1f03:face:b00c:0:26: Network is unreachable from Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook Current PHP SDK. My app was running ok. BUt from today any api call returning Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:1f03:face:b00c:0:26: Network is unreachable.

Here is my code

```
  try {
    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (Exception $e) {        
  echo $e->getMessage();        
  }
```

Is any one having this problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: yes. Its been working last 1 year. I have been maintaing it. It even worked yesterday.

Comment: well its probably what Igy said. Just a temporary server bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server's network or firewall is likely misconfigured; disable your IPV6 interface if you don't have IPV6 connectivity

Comment: Added IPV6 functionality to server and rebooted. This problem is gone.

Comment: @igy Thanks for your answer. I've been using the Facebook API for months with no problem, and suddenly tonight I started getting "Network is unreachable" on every call. My server is on Cloudways shared hosting. None of my code has changed in recent days. Is your guess that something must have changed with Cloudways? What is in my control / would you recommend for me to change to get this working again? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There is one more solution for this problem, found it on http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/06/03/solution-for-wordpress-curl-ipv6-error-network-is-unreachable/

You can simply force IPV4 resolve by setting the following **curl option** :

```
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

Comment: That didn't work.  Got the error: Invalid curl configuration option.

Comment: I get:
Curl failed with error #7: Failed to connect to 255.255.255.255: Network is unreachable